# Using rand() to get a number but that number can't be the number that was last generated

Tags: c++, random, std

I want to use `std::rand()` to generate a number between `0` and `amountOfNumbers`, but the generated number can't be the same number that was last generated.

I wrote this function:

```
void reroll() {
  int newRand;

  while (true) {
    newRand = std::rand() % (amountOfNumbers);
    if (newRand == lastNumber) {
      continue;
    }
    lastNumber = newRand;
    break;
  }

  // do something with newRand
  // ...
}
```

`amountOfNumbers` is just an int (> 1) that defines the upper bound (e.g. 5 so the possible number range is 0 to 4). `lastNumber` which is initially `-1` stores the last generated number.

I was wondering if there's a better way to write this.

The function seems to be working so far, but I'm not sure if my code is flawless... it looks kind of bad. That `while (true)` makes me feel a bit uneasy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you wish to do this (effectively de-randomizing your random numbers)?

Comment: There are better [random engines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than `std::rand()` available, that might not have these problems.

Comment: Might you want to generate consecutive numbers and then [`random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) instead?

Comment: You'll want to make sure `amountOfNumbers` is always more than `1`.

Comment: _"That `while (true)` makes me feel a bit uneasy."_ Why? You have a certain condition to `break;`.

Comment: I am generating different planets (`0` to `amountOfNumbers-1`) and I just want to make sure that the same planet isn't generated twice in a row

Comment: So, is it ok that the 3rd number matches the 1st?

Comment: Please understand random. I cap flip a coin four five times a and that is random

Comment: @EdHeal "Please understand random." Oh, I do. The randomly generated numbers are just fine as long as the same number isn't generated twice in a row.

Comment: A.d random may mean that. I guess you do not understand random as others pointed out. So the 1 2 8 is ok to have the same number

Comment: @EdHeal I don't get how that's not besides the point. I very much understand random, and it doesn't matter which random engine I use. For my purpose, the generated numbers are irrelevant as long as the same number isn't generated twice in a row. `rand()` is just a means to me that helps me accomplish the task stated in the op.

Comment: So you do not want random numbers

Comment: @EdHeal Let's just stop here, since you're clearly not interested in on-topic discussion. My problem is solved now, thanks to all who helped!

Comment: They are not random numbers - they have a condition imposed upon them

Comment: @EdHeal: you're simply wrong anyway... if you say `rand() % n` you have a pseudo-random number, despite there being a condition - namely that the numbers are in the rande 0..n-1.  Similarly, each call A.D. wants a pseudo-random number that's in some range but excluding the last-generated value.  The quality of (pseudo) randomness relates to how one of several possible values are selected, not whether the several possible values are contiguous or unchanging.

Comment: So like flipping a coin. The next one should not be like the last. So heads tails head tails. Not random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while true loop is definitely not good practise, I'd suggest doing something like this. But you should make it in the same structure as Michael's answer above like this:

```
void reroll(int lastNumber, int amountOfNumbers) {
  int newRand = std::rand() % (amountOfNumbers);

  while (newRand == lastNumber) {
    newRand = std::rand() % (amountOfNumbers);
  }

  lastNumber = newRand;
  return newRand;
}
```

Comment: I'm basing my new code on yours. `int newRand = std::rand() % (amountOfNumbers); while (newRand == lastNumber) { newRand = std::rand() % (amountOfNumbers); } lastNumber = newRand;` Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The code works but I'd structure it like this

```
int reroll(int n, int last) {
  while(true) {
    int v = std::rand() % n;
    if(v!=last)
      return v;
  }
}

void reroll() {
   ...
   int v = reroll(n, last);
   ...
}
```

Also you can avoid the need for the while loop altogether by generating values in a smaller range (1 less) and adjusting around `last`.

```
int reroll(int n, int last) {
  if(last==-1) 
    return std::rand() % n;
  int v = std::rand() % (n-1);
  if (v<last) return v
   return v+1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions.

Since you never declare lastNumber and amountOfNumbers, I am going to assume they are global.  It would be better to pass these as variables to the function instead.  Also, you should return the new number from the function instead of setting it as void.

The following code below will calculate a new roll. Instead of rerolling until there is a new roll, we will just take the random of the set of numbers, but one less. If the number is greater than or equal, we will add the one back in, thus avoiding the lastNumber.  The function then returns the newRand. Doing it this way will avoid the (albeit low) risk of an infinite loop, and it will always run in constant time.

```
int reroll(int lastNumber, int amountOfNumbers) 
{
  int newRand;

  newRand = std::rand() % (amountOfNumbers - 1);
  if (newRand >= lastNumber) {
    newRand++;
  }

  return newRand;
}
```

Comment: I like your loopless solution!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your value for `amountOfNumbers`, the modulus operation you've used might not guarantee an even distribution (which is a small part of your problem).

- For a start, if `amountOfNumbers` is greater than `RAND_MAX` there will be numbers you'll never see using this.
- Next, consider if you're using this to generate values between 0 and 6 (`[0,1,2,3,4,5]`) for a dice, and `RAND_MAX` is 7. You'll see the values `0` and `1` twice as often as the rest! In reality, `RAND_MAX` must be at least 32767 (whatever that means, which according to the standard isn't really much)... but *that* isn't evenly divisible by 6, either, so of course there will be some values that have a slight *bias*.

You *can* use modulus to reduce that range, but you'll probably want to discard the bias in the second problem. Unfortunately, due to the common implementation of `rand`, extending the range beyond `max` will introduce further bias.

```
unsigned int rand_range(unsigned int max) {
    double v = max > RAND_MAX ? max : RAND_MAX;
    v /= RAND_MAX;

    int n;
    do {
        n = rand();
    } while (RAND_MAX - n <= RAND_MAX % (unsigned int)(max / v));

    return (unsigned int)(v * n) % max;
}
```

This *still* doesn't guarantee that there won't be any repeating values, but at least any bias causing repeating values will have been reduced significantly. We can use a similar approach to the (currently) accepted answer to remove any repeated values, with minimal bias, now:

```
unsigned int non_repetitive_rand_range(unsigned int max) {
    if (max <= 1) {
        return 0; // Can't avoid repetitive values here!
    }

    static unsigned int previous;
    unsigned int current;
    do {
        current = rand_range(max);
    } while (current != previous);

    previous = current;
    return current;
}
```

---

On a technical note, this doesn't necessarily guarantee a problem to the solution either. This quote from the standard explains why:

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.

As a result, it is possible that some silly, obscure implementation might implement `rand` like so:

```
int rand(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

For such an implementation, there's no avoiding it: This implementation of `rand` would cause the code in this answer (and all the other current answers) to go into an *infinite loop*. Your only hope would be to re-implement `rand` and `srand`. Here's an example implementation given within the standard, should you ever have to do that:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;
int rand(void)   // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

You'll probably want to rename them to `my_rand` and `my_srand` respectively, and use `#define rand my_rand` and `#define srand my_srand` or use a find/replace operation.

Comment: Your `while (RAND_MAX - n <= RAND_MAX % (unsigned int)(v * max));` is not a good idea... say `max` is above `RAND_MAX`: your loop will spin until you fluke an `n` value of 0, which for common modern implementations where `RAND_MAX` is 2147483647 is a very, very long shot and correspondingly long spin.

Comment: For `amountOfNumbers< RAND_MAX`, anyone wanting to remove bias can just spin when after `n = rand()`, `n >= RAND_MAX / amountOfNumbers * amountOfNumbers`.

Comment: @TonyD Ooops! This shows how easy it is even for someone who has spent many hours thinking about this problem to get it wrong! How does it look, now?

Comment: *"How does it look, now?"* - honestly, still confusing: I don't understand why you're making it so convoluted, using `double` etc.. But, working through it: your first 2 lines amount to `double v = std::max(max / RAND_MAX, 1.0);`, then `RAND_MAX % (unsigned)(max / v)` simplies to either (when `v == 1.0`) `RAND_MAX % max`, or (when `v == max / RAND_MAX`) `RAND_MAX % (unsigned)(max / (max / RAND_MAX))` which is `RAND_MAX % (unsigned)(RAND_MAX)`, which is `0`. Unless I botched something there, irrespective of the intent of the `<=`, with 0 as potentially r.h.s. it's not looking good.

Comment: @TonyD Have you considered that many of those operands are floating point operands? Yes, when `RAND_MAX * 2` is given as `max` for example, the right hand side should be 0 because there won't be any bias to discard. If you think something's wrong, please write a testcase (in the form of a `rand()` that produces error-causing values, and a call to the function in question).

Comment: "Have you considered" - yes. Still - 0 could make sense as you say, and I should have continued the analysis. But, it's all broken - see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/012588e07fa7b17d), where I've created a fake `rand()` with `RAND_MAX 4` for easy testing Output breaks when `max > RAND_MAX`, e.g. for `max` `6`, outputs could be `0`, `1`, `3` or `4`. (If you end up with a fix that you want me to review, I'll expect decent test cases too next time. :-) )

Comment: @TonyD Indeed, there will be some values that are never returned, due to the very nature of expanding a range like [0..RAND_MAX] to a range like [0..2.25*RAND_MAX] (e.g. in your example). I suppose you could call `rand` multiple times, but then those values would be lost, too.

Comment: "you could call `rand` multiple times, but then those values would be lost, too" - yes, calling `rand` multiple times is how I've often handled this (and seen others do so).  I don't follow your "but then those values would be lost too" comment.  FWIW, the simplest approach to extending the range is just to have `superrand = rand() * (RAND_MAX + 1) + rand();`, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` allowing.

Comment: @TonyD Look at how `rand` is commonly implemented and you'll see... You won't ever get a repeat value, meaning there are still values you simply can't get. If you call `rand` twice to build a value, show me how you could ever get `0`.

Comment: Ahhh... I'm with you now... yes, random number generators have a *period* during which they don't repeat their internal state (and therefore the output sequence), and for some very primitive generators (as `rand()` implementations tend to be) their internal state is the last value returned and hence visible/returned values don't repeat until the period's up either.  That's normally neglected when `max` is much less than `RAND_MAX` (as a `%` operation means other `rand()` values generate the same output).  All up, a good reason to use a better random number generator (such as C++11 provides).

Comment: @TonyD ... depends if by *random* you mean *even distribution* (shuffle) or *unpredictable* (may have repetition).